# DefaultTableCellRenderer doesn't detect Integer and Date

Tags: java, date, integer, tablecellrenderer, defaulttablemodel

so in my old laptop (java version 1.8.0_292), the code was working.
My new laptop (java version 15.0.3), the code was not working.

```
String[] arrColumnName = new String[]{"Name", "Sex", "Balance", "Date"};
Date date = new Date();

Object[][] data = {
    {"Alex", "Man", 15000, date},
    {"Beatrix", "Woman", 25000, date}};
```

This is the DefaultTableModel :

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel() {
    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 2: return Integer.class;
            case 3: return Date.class;
            default: return String.class;
        }
    }
};
```

This is the Code :

```
public table() {
    setPreferredSize(null);
    setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    setAutoscrolls(true);

    model.setDataVector(data, arrColumnName);
    setModel(model);
    
    TableCellRenderer tableRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            System.out.println(column + " " + String.valueOf(value));
            
            if(value instanceof Integer) {
                System.out.println("value is Integer");
            } else if(value instanceof Date) {
                System.out.println("value is Date");
            } else {
                System.out.println("value is String");
            }
            
            return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
        
        
        
    };
    setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, tableRenderer);
}
```

I try to detect Integer and Date with this code and this is the result :

> 0 Alex
>
> value is String
>
> 1 Man
>
> value is String
>
> 0 Beatrix
>
> value is String
>
> 1 Woman
>
> value is String

As you can see, Integer and Date were not detected.

But, it was working fine, when I run the same code on my old laptop.

Please help. Sorry for my terrible english.

Best Regards,

Comment: Your output indicates column indices are always 0 and 1 so `case 2` and `case 3` will never match. Are those columns even displayed?

Comment: 1) There is no need for a custom renderer. All you need to do is override the `getColumnClass(...)` method of your table model. 2) Post a proper [me] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (I believe this was what @camickr too intended to refer to).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I finally found the solution.

I change the code from :
setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, tableRenderer);

to

setDefaultRenderer(String.class, tableRenderer);
setDefaultRenderer(Number.class, tableRenderer);
setDefaultRenderer(Date.class, tableRenderer);